# CSS3 Keyframe Animation Opacity Property not working in Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, opacity, keyframe

**The Animation**

```
@keyframes action-cycle {
  0%    {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    letter-spacing: -0.3em;
  }
  1%   {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    letter-spacing: -0.055em;
  }
  8%   {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  24%   {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
  25%   {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }

  //second
  100%  {
    opacity: 0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    transform: translateY(-100%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
}
```

**The DOM**

```
<ul class="header__text-overlay__action">
    <li class="action action--first">learn</li>
    <li class="action action--second">grow</li>
    <li class="action action--third">play</li>
    <li class="action action--fourth">work</li>
</ul>
```

The Animation is applied to every of the list-items with a specific animation delay:

```
.action{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: top-left;
    animation-name: action-cycle;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: $animation-length*1s;

    &--first{
    }

    &--second{
        // opacity: 1;
        animation-delay: ($animation-length/$item-count)*1s;
    }

    &--third{
        letter-spacing: -0.033em;
        // opacity: 1;
        animation-delay: ($animation-length/$item-count)*2s;
    }

    &--fourth{
        // opacity: 1;
        animation-delay: ($animation-length/$item-count)*3s;
    }
}
```

Somehow Opacity is the only property that is ignored by Safari.
I tested on Safari Version 9.0.2 and iPhone with iOS 9 latest.

**NOTE** Necessary vendor prefixes are automatically added by my preprocessor

Comment: use vendor prefix `-webkit-` for safari

Comment: @Raviteja vendor prefixes are already automatically added by my preprocessor